# Data Grid DataFormatString formatting not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, datagrid, databound-controls

I came accross an issue a few days ago which I'd completely forgotten about, and noticed it wasn't mentioned on SO.

In an ASP.Net document, a datagrid was created dynamically as part of a business intellgience tool.  The data format string was being set in the code behind, but was not being shown correctly on the rendered page.

As it turns out, the HtmlEncode property of the BoundField object MUST be set to false for this to work.

Unfortunately this problem doesn't manifest itself in the Visual studio 2005 Dev Webserver, and I only found the problem when I deployed the application to an IIS6 environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Htmlencode property must be set to false;

```
dim bf as New BoundField
bf.HtmlEncode = False
```